# Complex mesh deform with array for baking (necklace around the neck)

Tags: modifiers, baking

My problem may be (unnecesarily) complex as i tried alot of things mostly unsuccesfully. If you have any better solution than mine, please tell me !

I'm trying to make a collar for a character, my idea was to make only a part of it, then array/curve or shrinkwrap it around the character's neck, then finally bake it
(unfortunately i have to bake it, my game doesnt accept too much polys and the collar is too complex)

[image]

So i did a basic model, ready to receive the array modifier
Then made an basic armature of the body trying to make the collar fit

[image]

And tried various things from shrinkwrap with the armature, array or curve and it never came right.

Factually, maybe the bake doesn't need it, or maybe i could make it right on a plane? I don't know. Maybe you'll have the right answer too.

Comment: use a lattice. then use a lattice deform after the array. Use shrinkwrap on the lattice. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170584/how-can-i-wrap-an-array-grid-onto-a-different-object-without-the-objects-collap/170629#170629 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26023/in-blender-3d-is-there-any-function-like-flow-along-surface-in-rhino-3d

Comment: Since you want to use only render-bake (not actual geometry) why not render collar as it is now - flat? Unwrap basemesh (neck) into rectangle grid. So you just map it as texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's any easy way, except using the fantastic *[Wrapping Tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1A22jfG-sc&)* addon by Rich Colburn (which by the way allows you to create an unwrap version of any object).

You could do it with a cylinder used by the necklace as a *Surface Deform* object that would *shrinkwrap* around the neck, but when the shape begins to be complicated, this addon seems much more convenient.

- Once you've installed the addon, duplicate the neck. Select an edge as if you were going to mark seam, and rip it (<kbd>V</kbd>).

[image]

- In the *N* panel > *External Tools* tab, press *Create UV Shape*. It creates a new shapekey for the object.

[image]

- The panel is automatically refreshed, a *Shape Control* appears which acts like the *Shapekey* value. Tweak it to 1, the object flattens like a UV unwrap.

[image]

- Select your necklace, put it just over the neck object, in *Edit* mode make it follow the shape of the neck.

[image]

- Back to *Object* mode, select the necklace, shift select the neck, press *Bind to Surface*, then *Scene Update*.

[image]

- Move the Shape Control value back to 0, the necklace is now around the neck. For the necklace as well it has created a second shapekey, you can delete the basis shapekey if you want.

[image]

Comment: That did it ! 
Theres a bit of deform but i'll be able to fix it now, thanks you!

https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/26/5748.png

Comment: maybe make sure you have enough topology so that it can bend? Anyway yes it's not perfect, you probably need to make some corrections

Comment: I'm not sure i had enough topology anyway, the base itself is a disjointed amount of polys and i always have to fight with it if i want to achieve something. Modding is always a joy, uh? :D
Anyway i reduced stretching and the structure can do the job, thanks for the wonderful Wrapping Tools !

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the Q right - actual poly count of collar is too high for game so you want the collar bake as texture and use it as material.

- render it with with all needed passes (color, roughness, glossiness, normal, etc)
- Unwrap (U) basemesh - *Reset* than select one face and unwrap with *Follow Active Quads > Even* to get square grid
- create a new material with rendered passes

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the base model is a total mess so i doubt i could use any material on it and the wrapping tool did the job
althrough your method wil surely be useful for something else i have in mind like baked metal stripes on the dress, thanks you ^^

Comment: That is OK no problem, choose what fits you the best. Just wrapping geometry does not make it friendly for games as you mentioned. BTW When I said "base" mesh I didnt mean your character, but just the simplified neck part, that is (how you can see) invisible in render thanks to the material transparency so you can put it over your character. :)