# Deformities appearing when using Surface Deform and Shrinkwrap modifiers

Tags: shrinkwrap

I am having a lot of difficulty getting a cube, which I have flattened a bit, to properly deform around a cylinder.

[image]

This image is before I apply both shrinkwrap and surface deform modifiers. I do have plenty of vertices as well, made sure to subdivide both the cube and the plane.

[image]

The second image is what my cube is doing once I have applied the two modifiers. What is making my cube deform so weirdly and how do I fix it? I have tried moving the plane between the cube and the cylinder. I have kept the plane in the center of the Cube like the first picture, nothing changes the outcome.

Little FYI- Shrinkwrap modifier is applied to the Plane and the Surface Deform is applied to the cube. I have the most recent Blender update and I have watched multiple Shrinkwrap / Surface Deform videos to no avail.

Thank you for any and all advice and help in advance.

Comment: share blend file

Comment: Also you must try "ctrl + a" and apply rotation and scale to all of your objects one by one

Comment: If I've got you right, typically, you would [use a Lattice Modifier to do this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/170629/35559).. or, in this case, you could just solidify the plane after wrapping. It also looks as if your Shrinkwrap should be set to 'Project' along an axis, not closest point.

Comment: Sorry for late response. So a couple of things real quick. 
1, I am new and not sure how to share my blend file here. 
2. I do use ctrl+a and scale/roate all objects individually without issue.
3. I am unsure of how a Lattice Modifier works. 

So what i'm trying to do is take a thin cube that looks like a thick sheet of metal and get it to basically hug the cylinder face. I got it to work once and then the update from 2.92 to 2.93 happened and I haven't been able to make it work since.

Comment: Also figured out a work around that did just what I wanted.

What I ended up doing was going into wireframe mode, making a few edge loop cuts around the main object. highlighting a few faces and duplicating them. From there I separated the duplicated faces so that it was it's own individual object as well as has the perfect shape that forms to my cylinder. I renamed it and can now extrude, scale, whatever i want to the duplicate.